# Raspberry Pi + Qt4 + Opencv cross compile from windows

Tags: cross-compilation, opencv, c++, qt

Hi I want to know how to use opencv in raspberry pi. I have cross compiled qt raspberry from windows and succeed but I cannot add library opencv.